# Help center desperately needs more detail

Tags: discussion, site-scope

The [help/on-topic](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page needs some love.  Right now it consists of a total of one sentence of guidance on what is on-topic:

> "Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange is for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers."

I'm confident this community can do better than that.  Please suggest helpful text to further elaborate what topics are and aren't appropriate on this site, so that the help center page can be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I've added some examples of items that are definitely off-topic, but that list could do with beefing up (ideally with links to meta posts where available).

I think it would also be helpful to have more about what's definitely on-topic. If anyone wants to add specific suggestions (and links to example questions) there that'd be great.